# Questions about the standard library list

Tags: c++

In the past I've implemented a linked list using nodes.

I am looking at some of the properties of the standard library list and it has iterators and the appropriate member functions.

What are the iterators in a list exactly? Are they the node pointers?

For a vector, basically you have pointers to the element type and the data structures is built on an underlying dynamic array of that given type.

For the lists, it seems it is just a sequence of nodes, array of nodes. So are the iterators the node pointers rather than a pointer to the node data type?

Basically what I am asking is if for a vector I had this iterator:

```
tyepdef T* iterator;
```

Would the iterator for the list be

```
typedef node* iterator;
```

where node is something like:

```
template <class T> struct node {
    node() { next = 0; }
    node(T i, node* n = 0) : data(i), next(n) {}
    node* next;
    T data;
}
```

If this is the case, it seems that operations like dereferencing will have to be overloaded.

Comment: Welcome to the 1995. Iterators may be implemented in terms of node pointers, and indeed they often are. However they are abstract data types and most definitely are *not* bare `node` pointers. If they were, operators like `++` would not work on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::list<T>::iterator` objects internally point to a node but have operators which appropriately follow the pointers to next or previoys node. That is, they are not pointers as incrementing a pointer just adds one rather than follow a link. You can inagine a list iterator looks somewhat like this:

```
template <typename T>
class list_iterator {
    friend list<T>
    Node* node; 
    list_iterator(T* node):node(node) {}
    list_iterator& operator++() {
        node = node->next;
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() { return *node; }
     // ...
};
```

Comment: Is this iterator class nested in the list class?

Comment: @Dochevsky: the standard doesn't specify whether the iterator types are nested inside the class or not. I'm also not sure if it can be detected. Obviously, the name `list_iterator` wouldn't be used by a real implementation (this name isn't reserved) but conceptually the `std::list<T>::iterator` looks something like this (whether it really stores a `Node*` or, e.g., a `Node**` isn't specified either, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The iterator on lists should behave similar to the iterators on other sequence containers like `vector`. I.e. it should behave like a pointer to the list::value_type as if it were in an array or similar (with ++ and -- doing the expected operation going to next and previous). The internals of the holding structure aren't really exposed through the iterator. The iterator abstraction generally frees the programmer from thinking about how the data is stored. In the future, you could theoretically swap your `std::list` for a `std::vector` without changing your code, so long as you're only using operations available to both.